# Thymeleaf can not find resources in Springboot project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm creating a project with *Springboot* and *Thymeleaf*. I configured the whole project, found the template and the pages, so my template can not find the *css* and *js* files;

I'm use Springboot version 1.4.2.RELEASE.

Html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css}"/>
```

application.properties

```
# --- CONFIGURAÇÃO TYMELEAF ---
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
spring.thymeleaf.mode=HTML5
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
spring.thymeleaf.content-type=text/html
spring.thymeleaf.encoding=UTF-8
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
spring.thymeleaf.check-template-location=true
spring.thymeleaf.enabled=true
```

WebMvcConfigurerAdapter

```
@Override
     public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
             registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
                     .addResourceLocations("/resources/")
                     .addResourceLocations("/static/")
                     .addResourceLocations("/static/**")
                     .addResourceLocations("/resources/static/")
                     .addResourceLocations("/resources/static/**")
                     .addResourceLocations("/")
                     .addResourceLocations("/**");
     }
```

Folders

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**UPDATE**

I did as recommended and removed all the settings. So this time my page opens, so it does not load the starter page.

index

```
<div class="content-wrapper" th:replace="/starter :: content">

</div>
```

starter

```
<div class="content-wrapper" th:frament="content">
        <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
        <section class="content-header">
            <h1>
                Esse é o Prototipo do layout
            </h1>
            <ol class="breadcrumb">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Level</a></li>
                <li class="active">Here</li>
            </ol>
        </section>

        <!-- Main content -->
        <section class="content">

            <h1>Oi eu sou goku!!</h1>

        </section>
        <!-- /.content -->
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: The default configuration that comes with the spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf dependency is all you need for this scenario.  Try adding that jar and removing your custom configuration from both Java Config and application.properties

Comment: But it is not necessary to at least configure the prefix, suffix, context, etc ...?

Comment: Nope.  .html is already pre-configured for you if you use the spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf dependency.  And spring-boot-starter-web automatically serves any files within src/main/resources/{public, static, or resources}/**

Comment: th:href does not change?

Comment: No that's fine.  I'd keep that in case you ever change the context root.

Comment: Okay, I'll test the night and say if it works, thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript file doesn't load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41198735/javascript-file-doesnt-load)

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
```

you don't have to use th:href here.